# Verifying downloads wit Appium for Android devices

Tags: android, ios, pdf, download, appium

I'm automating some Android and iOS test scenarios using Appium (java). The following scenario came across.

When using Android. 
Within the app I click on a link. This link is a pdf file. The link navigates me outside of the app to the Android browser and the PDF file will be downloaded.

When conducting the scenario on iOS the PDF will be displayed in the browser itself, I then can validate the link in order to assess if I am on the right link. For android however this is not the case since it downloads the PDF instead of displaying it. Is there some way to asses the same for Android?

Thanks for the help,

Answer (score 0):

As you said in Android it directly download instead of displaying, since it's the default behavior of your app so I would suggest you to provide different assertions to validate the correct PDF gets downloaded.

(Some of the suggestions may not be applicable)

a. Assert the screen which gets displayed after successful completion of PDF

b. Check for Toast "Downloading/Download complete" and assert

c. Check for the notification message after completing the download

d. On click that notification the PDF file will get open and you can assert the name of the file/text

e. When you download the PDF file, check for the link on the browser with link you provided.

Comment: Hi Darshan,

Thanks for the reply. I will look into B tomorrow and will provide you with feedback. however can you zoom in on this method a but more? This might be useful for me.

For the other points:

A. No succes after completion of download
B. I will look into this, 
C. No notification message is shown :(
D. See above
E. Link turns into blank after it recognizes that it is a pdf :(


Cheers,